# Woocommerce - Dropdown variation product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have created a wordpress theme and installed Woocommerce in which I am also customizing all the templates.

I have a question that maybe someone with more experience can guide me.

Most of the products that I have are with variations but there is only one possible combination of each one. Example:

brush 1111

Variation 1 -> Number 10, Diameter 1, Outlet 2

Variation 2 -> Number 12, Diameter 2, Outlet 4

Variation 3 -> Number 14, Diameter 3, Outlet 10

URL example:

[Product example](https://escoda.addcom.es/product/4050/)

…

When viewing the product page by default, WordPress creates a Dropbox for each attribute, a total of three, but it doesn't make much sense since there is only one possible combination between variations:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a single Dropdown with all three different combinations of attributes:

[image]

When the dropdown is open:

[image]

I have been reviewing the code inside ../woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php of my theme and it is quite difficult to identify how I can load the parameters grouped by combinations. Even more difficult is once loaded, that I have achieved it, when selecting the add to cart button is activated and that when adding it knows the attributes that I have chosen.

The code I have modified is as follows:

```
        <?php
    //      NEW DROPDOWN MENU IN LINE

    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    if (count($available_variations) > 0) {

        $output = '<div class="product-variations-dropdown">
            <select id="available-variations" class="form-select product-selector mb-4" name="available_variations">';

                $output .= '<option value="">' . __('Choose a variation') . '</option>';

                foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
                    $option_value = array();

                    foreach ($variation['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_slug) {

                        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute);
                        $attribute_name = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name; // Attribute name
                        $term_name = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy)->name; // Attribute value term name

                        $option_value[] = $attribute_name . ': ' . $term_name;
                    }
                    $option_value = implode(' | ', $option_value);

                    $output .= '<option value="' . $variation['variation_id'] . '">' . $option_value . '</option>';
                }
                $output .= '
            </select>
        </div>';

        echo $output;

        echo end($attribute_keys) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post(apply_filters('woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__('Clear', 'woocommerce') . '</a>')) : '';
    
    }else{
        ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __('This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce'))); ?></p>
        <?php
    }
    
    ?>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

As I mentioned, it loads the different combinations line by line but I can't get the add to cart button to work and consequently it isn't added either.